# NiFi - Increasing QueryDatabaseTable performance to outperform Sqoop

Tags: apache-nifi, sqoop, netezza

I am using QueryDatabaseTable to read from a PDA/Netezza table that has about 70 million rows.

Nifi is set up as a single node instance with `bootstrap.conf` edited to give 16g RAM.

QueryDatabase table is using defaults except for

- `Max Rows Per Flow File`: 1000000
- `Output Batch Size`: 10

The result is that it is taking quite long, 1.5 hours for the full 70M, or approx. 1M records p/minute.

1. Are there other config changes I can experiment with to improve performance?
2. QueryDatabaseTable converts internally to Avro, is it possible to skip this conversion and just use text format from PDA/Netezza instead to possibly increase performance?

Planning also to set up a cluster soon but that will be 4 or 6 nodes so still looking to improve the performance down to 10mins or less.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QueryDatabaseTable is meant to run on the Primary Node only as it is a single-source for fetching. This means it will not scale to a distributed/parallel solution such as Sqoop. Also if you hypothetically have 3 nodes in a NiFi cluster but 10 in a Hadoop cluster with Sqoop, naturally you'll get more parallelism in the latter.

However, NiFi has the `GenerateTableFetch -> ExecuteSQL` pattern for this. Instead of a single processor on a single node doing the full fetch, GenerateTableFetch will instead generate a number of flow files that each contain a SQL statement to fetch a "page" of data from the table. You can then use ExecuteSQL to actually fetch the rows.

GenerateTableFetch still runs only on the primary node, but it does not fetch the rows itself; instead you'd distribute the flow files among the cluster nodes using either a `Remote Process Group -> Input Port` on the same cluster, or in recent versions of NiFi you can use a Load-Balanced Connection between GenerateTableFetch and ExecuteSQL.

Once the flow files are distributed among the cluster, each node can run ExecuteSQL on them in parallel and fetch a page of data at a time for downstream processing.

For the output format, as of NiFi 1.8.0 there is ExecuteSQLRecord which allows you to output the rows in any format that has a RecordSetWriter, which includes Avro, JSON, CSV, XML, Free-text (for custom textual formats), and you can even script your own for more complex, proprietary, or currently unsupported formats. For completeness there is also a QueryDatabaseTableRecord processor, but for this answer I'd like to discourage you from using it to solve your use case :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @mattyb.  Once I set up a cluster I will experiment with the GenerateTableFetch -> ExecuteSQL pattern.  I will also try using `ExecuteSQLRecord` with text output to see if it improves perf.  Also, would an increase in RAM significantly improve speeds for QDT processor?  (from 16g to 32g ??)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion 1M rows per minute is waaaay too slow for a Netezza system.

- External tables/unload should be 50-100 times faster
- single Select though ODBC to a fast client (I have used powercenter and SAS) 5-10 times faster

Please note that minimum query time on Netezza is close to 1/8 second, which means you need to get full value for ‘money’ in each query (quite possible btw) and I suspect that you framework tries to ‘over optimize’ this behind the scenes:)

Comment: 1M records p/minute

Comment: Oh - sorry - typo on my part, but my statement stands, I’ll edit my answer to say ‘minute’

Comment: Using an external table on a local disk on the NZ system I can get 100 mill rows out in a minute (150 bytes record size). If I use the ODBC clause and send the data to a server on 10G network I get half (50 mill rows per minute)